# Entity Framework : Why is DbContext a concrete Class and not an abstract class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I wonder why the `DbContext` class, which is the core class when using Entity Framework is a concrete class.

Indeed we never use this class directly, only by inheriting from it.

Wouldn't it be cleaner to have declared it as abstract? What are the reasons for it to be a concrete class?

Comment: `Indeed we never use this class directly, only by inheriting from it.` - I use it 'directly' a lot. Calling `SaveChangesAsync` for example is using it's implementation directly. Of course there are virtual methods too, but it does have it's own job to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only people who made this decision can tell you for sure. However, note that there is no behavior in `DbContext` which *must* be provided by child classes, so if you make it abstract - that's only because you want to prevent using it directly. But it *can* be used directly:

```
using (var ctx = new DbContext("EntityConnectionString")) {
    var errors  = ctx.Set<Error>().ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(errors.Length);
}
```

If you pass entity connection string (or name of it in app.config) - it can build model from your emdx model (and it can be used directly in other scenarios too). With that you can make queries, save changes and so on as usual, instead of declared `DbSet` properties you just use `Set<T>` method.

Since it's not broken when using by itself - I see not much reason to prevent that by making it abstract.

Comment: _Only people who made this decision can tell you for sure._ Great remark. Design decision can only be explain by developers of EF library.

Comment: "note that there are no abstract methods in `DbContext`" - the absence of abstract methods in this class doesn't really tell us much since, by definition, if the class had such methods it would be `abstract` anyway and so the original question would not have been asked.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that wording was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> ... we never use this class directly ...

Although it's *predominantly* used by deriving a type from it and adding additional `DbSet` based properties to it, it *can* be used in it's own right:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace PlayAreaCSCon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mb = new DbModelBuilder();
            mb.RegisterEntityType(typeof(Foo));
            var pinfo = new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008");
            var ctx = new DbContext("Server=.;Database=Flange;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
                     mb.Build(pinfo).Compile());
            ctx.Set<Foo>().Add(new Foo { ID = 1 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Just created a `Foos` table in my `Flange` database and inserted a row. Since it's fully functional in its own right, there's no *reason* to prevent people from using it like this, if they choose to do so.